# Какой DOCTYPE использовать для фреймов?

Tags: html, doctype

Какой мне использовать DOCTYPE, такой:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

или

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

если в моей вёрстке используются фреймы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ещё проще:

```
<!doctype html>
```